# Double display issue in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I was almost done displaying this page. However, there is a problem in displaying this page where it displayed twice rather than once. It looks weird when you view. There is a screenshot below to see the image. So definitely, I have error(s) in displaying the webpage. I think PHP code is my profile. Here's the code:

```
<?php
require('dbconnect.php');//Connects to the database

$id=$_GET['hf_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM healingfood WHERE hf_id='$id'";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
    die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}

//stores the result of the query
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $hf_id=$record['hf_id'];
    $hf_title=$record['hf_title'];
    $a_id=$record['a_id'];
    $hf_image=$record['hf_image'];
    $hf_description=$record['hf_description'];
    $hf_benefits=$record['hf_benefits'];
    $hf_source=$record['hf_source'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM author";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query2))
{
    die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);

while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $a_id=$record2['a_id'];
    $a_lname=$record2['a_lname'];
    $a_fname=$record2['a_fname'];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title><?php print $record['hf_title'];?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style type="text/css" href="../style.css"><!--External CSS-->
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="../welcome.html" width="100%" height="20%" frameborder="0"><iframe><!--inserts an HTML file using iFrame-->
    <br>
    <iframe></iframe>

    <table border="1" id="1" width="100%"><!--This table cannot be inserted using an iFrame beacuse it will pop in the whole website within a website-->
    <tr><!--Creates tabs-->
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../homepage.html" title="Home page">Home</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../recipes.html" title="Recipes">Recipes</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../healing_food.html" title="Healing Food">Healing Food</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../videos.html" title="Videos">Videos</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></th>
        <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="admin.php" title="Admin">Admin</a></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

    <div id="three">
        <p id="homepagetab" align="center"><?php print $record['hf_title'];?></p>
        <p id="normal" align="center"><?php echo "by ".$record2['a_fname']." ".$record2['a_lname'].""?></p>
        <img src="<?php print $record['hf_image'];?>" alt="Celery" width="20%" align="right">
        <p id="noindent"><b>Description:</b></p>
        <p id="normal"><?php print $record['hf_description'];?></p>
        <br>

        <p id="normal"><b>Benefits:</b> <?php print $record['hf_benefits'];?></p>
        <br>
        <p id="normal"><b>Source:</b> <a href=" <?php print $record['hf_source'];?> "><?php print $record['hf_source'];?></a></p>
        </div>

    <br>

    <iframe src="../copyright.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe><!--To determine who created this website-->
</body>
<?php } } ?>

</html>
```

What is/are my error(s)?

[image]

UPDATE: Only the author is still being double displayed.

```
$id=$_GET['hf_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM healingfood WHERE hf_id='$id'";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
    die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}

//stores the result of the query
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$hf_id=$record['hf_id'];
$hf_title=$record['hf_title'];
$hf_image=$record['hf_image'];
$hf_description=$record['hf_description'];
$hf_benefits=$record['hf_benefits'];
$hf_source=$record['hf_source'];

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title><?php print $record['hf_title'];?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" style type="text/css" href="../style.css"><!--External CSS-->
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="../welcome.html" width="100%" height="20%" frameborder="0"><iframe><!--inserts an HTML file using iFrame-->
<br>
<iframe></iframe>

<table border="1" id="1" width="100%"><!--This table cannot be inserted using an iFrame beacuse it will pop in the whole website within a website-->
<tr><!--Creates tabs-->
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../homepage.html" title="Home page">Home</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../recipes.html" title="Recipes">Recipes</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../healing_food.html" title="Healing Food">Healing Food</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../videos.html" title="Videos">Videos</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="admin.php" title="Admin">Admin</a></th>

</tr>
</table>
<br>

<div id="three">
    <p id="homepagetab" align="center"><?php print $record['hf_title'];?></p>
    <?php

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM author";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query2))
{
    die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}

$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);

while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $a_lname=$record2['a_lname'];
    $a_fname=$record2['a_fname'];
?>
    <p id="normal" align="center"><?php echo "by ".$record2['a_fname']." ".$record2['a_lname'].""?></p>
    <?php } ?>
    <img src="<?php print $record['hf_image'];?>" alt="<?php print $record['hf_title'];?>" width="20%" align="right">
    <p id="noindent"><b>Description:</b></p>
    <p id="normal"><?php print $record['hf_description'];?></p>
    <br>

    <p id="normal"><b>Benefits:</b> <?php print $record['hf_benefits'];?></p>
    <br>
    <p id="normal"><b>Source:</b> <a href=" <?php print $record['hf_source'];?> "><?php print $record['hf_source'];?></a></p>
    <?php }  ?>
    </div>

<br>

<iframe src="../copyright.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe><!--To determine who created this website-->
```

UPDATE 2: I have resolved the problem by appending a_id on the URL after hf_id. And then, I used $id2=$_GET['a_id']; followed by $query2 = "SELECT * FROM author WHERE a_id='$id2'"; . And, it finally worked.

Comment: Do you have two records with the same `id`? You shouldn't have the `html` declaration inside the `while` loop. You also are open to SQL injections with this code..

Comment: your hole page is in a while loop

Comment: The great thing about mysqli/PDO is that they afford the use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <?php
require('dbconnect.php');//Connects to the database

$id=$_GET['hf_id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM healingfood WHERE hf_id='$id'";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query))
{
die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}

//stores the result of the query
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

while($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$hf_id=$record['hf_id'];
$hf_title=$record['hf_title'];
$a_id=$record['a_id'];
$hf_image=$record['hf_image'];
$hf_description=$record['hf_description'];
$hf_benefits=$record['hf_benefits'];
$hf_source=$record['hf_source'];

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM author";

if(!mysqli_query($link,$query2))
{
die("Sorry. There's a problem with the query.");
}
$hf_benefits = $record['hf_benefits'];
$result2 = mysqli_query($link,$query2);
$hf_title = $record['hf_title'];
$hf_source = $record['hf_source'];
$hf_description = $record['hf_description'];
}


?>

<html>
<head>
<title><?php print $hf_title;?></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" style type="text/css" href="../style.css"><!--    External CSS-->
</head>

<body>
<iframe src="../welcome.html" width="100%" height="20%" frameborder="0">        <iframe><!--inserts an HTML file using iFrame-->
<br>
<iframe></iframe>

<table border="1" id="1" width="100%"><!--This table cannot be inserted     using an iFrame beacuse it will pop in the whole website within a website-->
<tr><!--Creates tabs-->
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../homepage.html" title="Home page">Home</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../recipes.html" title="Recipes">Recipes</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../healing_food.html" title="Healing Food">Healing Food</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../videos.html" title="Videos">Videos</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../contact.html" title="Contact Us">Contact Us</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="../about.html" title="About Us">About Us</a></th>
    <th align="center" width="14%"><a href="admin.php" title="Admin">Admin</a></th>
</tr>
</table>
<br>
<?php
while($record2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
$a_id=$record2['a_id'];
$a_lname=$record2['a_lname'];
$a_fname=$record2['a_fname'];
  ?>
    <div id="three">
    <p id="homepagetab" align="center"><?php print $hf_title;?>     </p>
    <p id="normal" align="center"><?php echo "by ".$record2['a_fname']." ".$record2['a_lname'].""?></p>
    <img src="<?php print $record['hf_image'];?>" alt="Celery" width="20%" align="right">
    <p id="noindent"><b>Description:</b></p>
    <p id="normal"><?php print $hf_description;?></p>
    <br>

    <p id="normal"><b>Benefits:</b> <?php print $hf_benefits;?> </p>
    <br>
    <p id="normal"><b>Source:</b> <a href=" <?php print $hf_source;?> "><?php print $hf_source;?></a></p>
    </div>

<br>
<?php } ?>
<iframe src="../copyright.html" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">    </iframe><!--To determine who created this website-->
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to close the PHP. After that, there is still some double display on the tabs. And, no data is retrieved.

Comment: what are you trying to display

Comment: the table? because you while loop was surrounding the whole html body block

Comment: if you could tell me what you are trying to display i could fix it

Comment: What if I'll use the AND function in the while loop?

Comment: Okay, I quite get it right now. I just put the second while loop just before the title. However, there is still double display on the author only. That is my only remaining problem to make it perfect.

Comment: i am not quiet understanding what you are trying to do

Comment: it looks like it works but try what i just now edited i changed some variables

Comment: to me your code makes more scene now that i changed it

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Please, check my updated code on my question to see the whole.

Comment: I added the third author in my database and is now triple displayed.

Comment: How about trying this code: if(isset($_GET['a_id'])) ?

Comment: sir Jack, I finally got it. I just appended the a_id after hf_id . And then, I use get a_id . It finally worked. Thank you very much for your help.